# Github webhook for codepileline not triggering when there is a commit in git repo

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, git-webhooks

I have set up an aws code pipeline where Git is used for the repository and have chosen GitHub webhooks as change detection mode.

the pipeline works great when I manually trigger the pipeline by clicking on the Release change button.

But when I try a commit and then push into my mater there is no activity in the pipeline.
I am not sure if the git webhook is working correctly or is there any additional configuration that I am missing.

I am just a user of the git repository which is on git hub.

Could anyone suggest what is that I am missing?

edit :

[image]

Have added the token and also repo and admin:repo as you can see it showed it has been used

This is my git repo :

[image]

as you can see there a commit a few minutes back.

This is pipeline's source :

[image]

As you can see there are no actions by it from past 18th min which was triggering it manually

when you click the GitHub link that source it points to the repo and the same branch and also has the latest commit info (shared in the pic of git repo)

EDIT:
here is the thing I get which seems to be good.
[![enter image description here][4]][4]

But I could also see there is no webhook created on the git hub repo, Should I put it manually?

Comment: Have you followed the instructions for what the tokens permissions should look like: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-GitHub.html#action-reference-GitHub-auth? And are you sure the changes are being deployed to the branch you reference in your pipeline?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams I haven't followed this token permission steps.
for the second question: yes, because when I manually trigger the pipeline. It is working

Comment: It will only trigger when code changes in that branch though, whereas triggering it will just get the latest code :)

Comment: @ChrisWilliams I switched the change detection to code pipeline periodic check. It seems to be working good

Comment: @ChrisWilliams I designed the code pipeline through the console. Documents state AWS takes care of OAuth tokens. Did I understand it right or I am missing something again :(

Comment: Go to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/GitHub-authentication.html#GitHub-view-oauth-token and follow stepsto check if the tokens permissions are there in GitHub.

Comment: @ChrisWilliams I am adding the things I tried in questions

Comment: If you click the information on the GitHub source it should give you more information over exactly what the GitHub parameters are

Comment: @ChrisWilliams got it it's working :D, The issue was that I didn't have full access to the repo to create the webhook from my git credentials.

Thank you for your patients as always you're a lifesaver

Comment: No problem, glad this is now resolved for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This likely comes down to one of the below scenarios.

The first scenario is that the permissions are not correctly configured within your GitHub account. Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-GitHub.html#action-reference-GitHub-auth) the below permission must be attached to the generated token:

- `repo`
- `admin:repo_hook`

The second scenario is that the branch itself is not have changes deployed to it, its very important that the branch specified is the one receiving the changes. If this branch does not have any changes then the pipeline will not trigger until there are changes.